# Jackson Json Procerssing in Scala to java object

Tags: java, scala, jackson

I am trying to serialize a string to java object in scala codebase. I am not sure if this is even compatible, but the same code works for scala case class object but not for java pojo.

Java Pojo :

```
@Data
public class JobConfigTest {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    public JobConfigTest(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }
}
```

Scala object :

```
case class job (name : String)
```

Serialition Code :

```
val str : String = "{\"name\": \"hotel\"}";

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```

This works :

```
val a1 = mapper.readValue(str, classOf[job]
```

This gives error :

```
val a2 = mapper.readValue(str, classOf[JobConfigTest])
```

Error log :

```
Unrecognized field "name" (class com.content.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest), not marked as ignorable (37 known properties: "endWith", "succeed", "be", "regex", "startWith", "defined", "matchPattern", "empty", "not", "contain", "stackDepth", "styleName", "key", "writable", "a", "subjectWithAfterWordRegistrationFunction", "length", "they", "it", "an", "typeCheck", "readable", "value", "compile", "exist", "decided", "subjectRegistrationFunction", "theSameInstanceAs", "assertionsHelper", "size", "fullyMatch", "after", "include", "behave", "determined", "sorted", "have"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"name": "Hotel"}"; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.content.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest["name"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class com.content.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest), not marked as ignorable (37 known properties: "endWith", "succeed", "be", "regex", "startWith", "defined", "matchPattern", "empty", "not", "contain", "stackDepth", "styleName", "key", "writable", "a", "subjectWithAfterWordRegistrationFunction", "length", "they", "it", "an", "typeCheck", "readable", "value", "compile", "exist", "decided", "subjectRegistrationFunction", "theSameInstanceAs", "assertionsHelper", "size", "fullyMatch", "after", "include", "behave", "determined", "sorted", "have"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"name": "Hotel"}"; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.content.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest["name"])
```